# Сдвинуть li на высоту предыдущего открывающегося списка

Tags: css, list, ul

Есть список `ul li`, в котором находится еще один список. Когда после отработки скрипта во вложенный список будут вноситься данные, он будет накладываться на следующий `li` и так далее. Как сделать, что бы следующий `li` съезжал вниз на величину вложенного списка?

```css
#list_quest {
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(8, 61, 99, 0.9);
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Andika', sans-serif;
}

#ul_quests {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.quest {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 14px 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(112, 219, 255);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(112, 219, 255);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 17px 0px 17px 0px;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px rgba(112, 219, 255, 0.5), 1px 1px 5px rgba(112, 219, 255, 1);
}

#q_count,
#q_watcher,
#q_date,
#q_addresses {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 35px;
}

#ul_addresses {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#b_quest_show {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}

#b_quest_show:hover {
  color: white;
}

#ul_addresses li:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin: 13px 0px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgba(105, 155, 229, .2);
  line-height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid rgb(112, 219, 255);
  border-right: 1.5px solid rgb(112, 219, 255);
  border-radius: 0px 17px 0px 17px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="list_quest">
  <ul id="ul_quests">
    <li class="quest">
      <div id="q_count">1</div>
      <div id="q_date">27-08-2017</div>
      <div id="q_watcher">Иванова</div>
      <div id="q_addresses">
        <ul id="ul_addresses">
          <li id="b_quest_show">Показать все адресса</li>
          <li>Лит 14</li>
          <li>Лит 14</li>
          <li>Лит 14</li>
          <li>Лит 14</li>
          <li>Лит 14</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="quest">
      <div id="q_count">2</div>
      <div id="q_date">29-08-2017</div>
      <div id="q_watcher">Петрова</div>
      <div id="q_addresses">
        <ul id="ul_addresses">
          <li id="b_quest_show">Показать все адресса</li>
          <li>Лит 20</li>
          <li>Лит 20</li>
          <li>Лит 20</li>
          <li>Лит 20</li>
          <li>Лит 20</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Если нельзя увеличивать высоту элемента списка первого порядка (.quest) и нельзя менять разметку, то css'ом тут не обойдешься, нужен либо js, либо менять разметку, скажи что из этого допускается, будем думать.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, если изменить высоту, первого списка, то нужно придумывать выравнивание для текста внутри оного, но думаю это не страшно. js как вариант я не рассматривал, но если не выйдет на css, буду думать в его сторону. А разметку лучше не трогать...

Comment: С разметкой как минимум одна проблема - нельзя на странице использовать одинаковые id.

Comment: Это да, там где можно я заменю, а id в дивах будут еще нумероваться скриптом

Comment: Кстати, если изменить у `div` `id` на `class`, все ломается и мы получаем 2 списка рядом, а все `li` в них - вертикально в одну линию

Comment: Не знаю, был бы макет, я бы вообще это все дело переверстал xDDD

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в конец, это решает проблему?

```
#q_addresses{
  float:none;
}
```

А вообще, как по мне флоаты тут ни к чему использовать.

Comment: Не решает, если добавить флот, все внешние списки станут в ряд, а нужно что бы были обычным вертикальным списком

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uxjq9405/

Comment: Костыльно конечно, но под условия задачи подходит, только я бы ещё добавил #q_addresses { clear: both; } #ul_addresses li:nth-child(1) { text-align: left; }